# Can't include ActiveModel::Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have a class TaskBuilder to which I want to add various ActiveModel methods so it can take advantage of ActionPack. As I understand it, in Rails 4, this will do the trick:

```
class TaskBuilder
  include ActiveModel::Model
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
task_builder.rb:2:in `<class:TaskBuilder>': 
  uninitialized constant TaskBuilder::Active_Model (NameError)
```

Note that originally I only intended to use validations, and simply included that module, with no issues, e.g.,

```
class TaskBuilder
  include ActiveModel::Validations
```

which worked fine. I am using Rails 4.0.0. What's going on here?

Comment: Does adding `require 'active_model'` help?

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/Willianvdv/9162257. Is this a normal rails project?

Comment: `require 'active_model'` appears to have fixed it. If someone can explain why that was necessary I'll accept that answer. There's nothing particularly fancy about the project set up.

Comment: It wasn't a typo, but when I exited guard, restarted and ran my specs, everything worked with `require 'active_model'` still added. Then I removed that line, saved the file, guard ran my specs again, and I didn't get the error. So issue resolved I guess, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `require 'active_model'` was mentioned in this old [rails issue #5768](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5768) as being necessary due to the lazy loading of classes (autoload).

```
require 'active_model'

class TaskBuilder
  include ActiveModel::Model
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code.
Please check that you have `include ActiveModel::Model` and not `include Active_Model::Model` (**NOTE**: _ should not be there) in your `TaskBuilder` class.

```
class TaskBuilder
  include ActiveModel::Model    ### Match this
```

Comment: Good idea, but there's no underscore; what I've got matches. See the comments above - adding `require 'active_model'` at the top of the file seems to have fixed it, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @SteveRowley thats very strange because i simulated the same configuration and i don't need to `require active_model`.

Comment: BUT look at the error you posted "TaskBuilder::Active_Model (NameError)". why does it say Active_Model?

Comment: Those are two good questions to which I would love to have an answer.

Comment: @SteveRowley For fun, `include Active_Model::Model` and run the code. You will get the exact same error which you posted.